# Is it possible to remove one strand of double stranded DNA in vivo?

Tags: genetics, biotechnology, synthetic-biology, systems-biology

Assume we do have a double stranded DNA sequence in human cells, say

```
...ATCGATATCGATATTGCAGAGCATAGCTATAA...
...TAGCTATAGCTATAAGCTCTCGTATCGATATT...
```

Now I want to cleave one strand, such that I do have

```
...ATC..........................TAA...
...TAGCTATAGCTATAAGCTCTCGTATCGATATT...
```

The distance is not so important to me, so it can be 20 bp I remove or 1000s. Hence, if I need some PAM or so and it is not nearby the target deletion site, I will simply move in 5' resp. 3' direction until I find it and cleave there, as long it is ensured that I have the target site single stranded then.

I would be very grateful I you could help me here!

Comment: I don't understand what your question is - why are you trying to remove a single strand *in vivo*? What is PAM in this context? Please [edit] your question to add additional explanations and details.

Answer (score 1):

Both TALEN and ZFN gene editing technologies use a pair of single-strand endonucleases that ultimately lead to a double strand break. Cas9 in CRISPR-Cas technology, however, cuts both the DNA strands (there are some Cas enzymes in certain bacterial species that cut only a single strand [[ref]](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26545076)).

> [image]
>
> ---
>
> <sup>*Image courtesy: http://www.xenbase.org/other/static/CRISPr.jsp*</sup>

So, if you use a single unit of the pair, you can cut one strand of the DNA. You can use another nuclease to impart a cut at another site in the same strand. This will still not lead to the removal of the DNA sequence between the two cut sites. There is no available technology that can do this *in-vivo.* Possibly (a wild guess), you can use a modified oligonucleotide (or even an IVT synthesized RNA) that can bind to this stretch of sequence and break its interaction with the other DNA strand. In any case, a stretch of ssDNA would not be stable and be repaired quickly by polymerase.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Another thing that would be sufficient for my project would be that on a specific site the DNA gets unwinded in vivo (perhaps by some CAS enzyme like dCas9, though others might be better suited here). Then one of the strands might be "hidden" by the machinery, but the other one should be accessible to toy around with it. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: @tobias Possibilities are infinite but we should go with the one that is simplest in principle and is easy to implement.

Comment: Sure :). What would you suggest for it?

Comment: @tobias I don't think such a protein has been engineered yet. That would be a research project in itself and you would have to do many experimental try-outs. So, I cannot suggest much regarding that- you would have to try it. What I said in the answer (the guess) would be the first thing that I would try because it is easy.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Regarding the second question, where I try to have a large strand of ssDNA, could I fuse dCAS9 to a helicase, such that the dCAS9 bind in sequence-specific manner to the dsDNA, opens the DNA and the helicase opens it for, say several tens of bps. Is that realistic?

Comment: @tobias Sounds good but as I said, it may be a research project in itself. Sometimes even the most perfect designs on paper may not work out in the lab (happened to me three times). There is always some risk with designing a new tool. It may or may not work. If you wish, then you can try. Moreover, even the design step would involve a lot of thinking (how to fuse the proteins, how will the domains interact etc).